# How do we convert any special characters in textbox to certain format

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I want to convert any special characters entered in infopath textbox into under score.Using the translate function, in the below example I am able to replace the space with under score

```
translate(fileName, " ","_")
```

Since translate function takes only three parameters then how can we check all the special characters? My target is if any special characters including space is entered into the text box it should automatically replace these special characters with under score ("_")

Answer (score 0):

what if you reverse it. If it is not A-Z, then convert it

or try this:

```
translate(field1, "!@#%^&", "_")
```